# What does ((111 >= 111) | !(TRUE)) & ((4 + 1) == 5) mean?

Tags: r

I am currently learning R and I came across this expression:

((111 >= 111) | !(TRUE)) & ((4 + 1) == 5)

Does anybody know what it means? I tried to ask my econometrics prof, but he does not use R by himself. SO he didn't know.

Thank you.

Comment: its a logical expression, for more info: http://www.r-tutor.com/r-introduction/basic-data-types/logical

Comment: The `!(TRUE)` is `FALSE`, By using `|` it would depend on the `(111>=111)` to get TRUE/FALSE.  So, if that expression is `FALSE` then, `FALSE|FALSE` will be FALSE combining with `&` it would always be `FALSE` whatever be the logical outcome of `(4+1) ==5`

Comment: Well I know that it is a logical expression, but I don't the essence of it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Where did you come across the expression? It's very likely that this is just to get you thinking about evaluations and booleans in R. Essentially, work inside of the parentheses and work outward until there is nothing left to evaluate. Let's work through it step by step:

`((111 >= 111) | !(TRUE)) & ((4 + 1) == 5)`

#### Step 1:

`(111 >= 111)`. Well, this is `TRUE` because 111 == 111. So now we have the following `(TRUE | !(TRUE)) & ((4 + 1) == 5)`.

#### Step 2:

`!(TRUE)`. `!` means "not" and simply reverses a boolean value. So, `!TRUE` is the same as `FALSE` and `!FALSE` is the same as `TRUE`. Therefore, we're left with this: `(TRUE | FALSE) & ((4 + 1) == 5)`.

#### Step 3:

`(TRUE | FALSE)`. `|` means "OR" and checks to see if **at least one** of the conditions is `TRUE`. Here we have two condtions, `TRUE` and `FALSE`. Since one of them is `TRUE`, this whole expression evaluates to `TRUE`. We therefore now have `TRUE & ((4 + 1) == 5)`.

#### Step 4:

`((4 + 1) == 5)`. This is obviously `TRUE` since `4 + 1 == 5`, so we now have `TRUE & TRUE`.

#### Step 5:

`TRUE & TRUE`. `&` means "and" and it checks to see that **all** of the conditions are `TRUE`. Since our two conditions are `TRUE` and `TRUE`, it's true that all conditions are `TRUE` and therefore this evaluates to `TRUE`.

So, at the end of 5 steps of evaluation, we find that the entire expression evaluates to `TRUE`. You'd benefit greatly from reading through the link @mtoto provided in the comments to help you understand this better.

Hope that helps.

Comment: Are you familiar with the swirl script in R? I came across the expression when I had to answer if the vector is true or false.